# What does it mean if my 5 year old cat isn't eating and has changed behavior?

Tags: cats, behavior, eating

My cat is usually really social. Is all over you at night meowing and wanting attention. For the past few days, he spent the nights sleeping under the bench at the foot of the bed and doesn't come out, even for food and treats. Typically he eats so quickly that we have to keep him away from the other cats food!He doesn't want to go outside anymore, where normally he would cause havoc to be let out.

For reference, he is about five years old, an indoor/outdoor cat. I took him to the vet a few years ago and they noticed that he had a slightly enlarged heart.

What should I do? Is this a wait and see situation, or a call the vet in the morning one?

Comment: If it were me, I'd call the vet.

Comment: you need to take your cat to the vet as soon as possible when a cat stop eating it is an emergency.

Comment: Get your cat to the vet asap.

Answer (score 6):

Any time your cat stops eating it's something to be concerned about. I suggest a trip to the vet to figure out what is wrong. There are a lot of possible causes, and your vet is your best resource.

Answer (score 2):

I had a 5 year old cat that had gotten to be 20 pounds. He was very active and acted normal. Then he hid from me and didn't eat or drink anything for one day and night.  The next afternoon I took him to the vet.  He was suffering from diabetic ketoacidosis and they kept him and tried everything but he died 2 days later.  I was devastated.  Don't wait 2 days to take a hiding cat that is not eating or drinking.